# Unique URI/string rule with callback for Laravel 4 models

Tags: database, model, laravel, uri, unique

Absolutely love Laravel atm, but I'm struggling with one aspect - dealing with tidy string-based uri's for created objects and maintaining uniqueness within the database.

So for example I have a `Users` table, with the following fields:

```
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('uri')->unique();
    });
```

A user inputs their name via a form, then I use Laravels `Str::slug($value, $seperator);` to convert their name to a valid URI (so 'Joe Bloggs' becomes 'joe-bloggs'), which is then used within Routes to pinpoint a user. Now, I can do this fine, but the problem is that I want to catch duplicates on validation and (I'm assuming with a Mutator) append a number to the end of the string if an entry already exists within the database using this:

```
/**
 * Append incrementing number to a string
 *
 * @param  string  $str
 * @param  string  $separator
 * @param  int  $first
 * @return string
 */
public static function increment_string($value, $separator = '-', $first = 1)
{
    preg_match('/(.+)'.$separator.'([0-9]+)$/', $value, $match);

    return isset($match[2]) ? $match[1].$separator.($match[2] + 1) : $value.$separator.$first;
}
```

Is there a more efficient or robust way of handling this situation in Laravel so that a duplicate database entry is modified rather than returned with error? Are model mutators the way to go in this instance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PACKAGE SOLUTION**
Not a direct answer to your question, but check out this awesome package that's ment for automatic slug generation. It deals with the unique issue, you can also configure a lot it's features. It works great, I use it myself.

> **Eloquent-Sluggable** 
>   Easy creation of slugs for your Eloquent models in Laravel 4.

https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable

**CUSTOM SOLUTION**
 
Coupling [this solution](http://chrishayes.ca/blog/code/laravel-4-generating-unique-slugs-elegantly) with soft deletes, might work just fine with a mutator (code not tested but it should do). Although it's not perfect as the numbering of deleted items will not be reused.

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{

    protected $softDelete = true;

    // rest of your code

    public function setUriAttribute($value)
    {
        $slug = Str::slug($value);
        $slugCount = count( $this->withTrashed()->whereRaw("slug REGEXP '^{$slug}(-[0-9]*)?$'")->get() );
        $this->attributes['uri']  = ($slugCount > 0) ? "{$slug}-{$slugCount}" : $slug;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks Gadoma! I'll check that package out as it looks most promising. Although I like the simplicity of the custom solutions there is a major flaw in that it replies on count, so if you have joe-bloggs, joe-bloggs-1, joe-bloggs-2 but delete joe-bloggs-1 then the count would reduce, but because joe-bloggs-2 already exists it could feasibly fail unique validation due to the potential for count to vary downwards.

Comment: yes you are right, but it could work fine if you couple it with soft deletes, I edited the answer to include that